# Custom numbering and Devanagari numbering of first line of each para in reledpar

Tags: numbering, reledpar, devanagari

I am typesetting a facing-page translation of a Sanskrit text using `reledpar`. What I currently have is this, with each fifth line numbered on both the left and right pages.

[image]

What I want is something like the one below. I want a manually set verse number (e.g. 30.1, 30.12, etc.) to be printed in both the left and right margins. In some cases two or more verses are translated together, so automatic para numbering will not do and I will have to manually set the verse number(s).

[image]

So what I want to accomplish is twofold

1. Instead of numbering every fifth line, I want to number the first line of each paragraph (i.e., at every `\pstart`).
2. I want the numbers to be set manually, rather than automatically.
3. I want the numbers on the left side to be in Devanagari.

How do I achieve this? Below is an MWE with the sample text which produces the output in the first image above.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,typography/prehyphenchar=]{sanskrit}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Charis SIL}
% \babelfont[sanskrit]{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Devanagari]{Noto Sans Devanagari}
\babelfont[sanskrit]{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz,Script=Devanagari]{Adishila}
% Need to scale the Devanagari font to match the glyph height of Roman font
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{10}{15}\selectfont
\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
\begin{sloppypar}\justifying\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}
\noindent{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{\relscale{1.4}३०.१}}\\
\noindent{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{\relscale{1.4}आतोद्यं सुषिरं नाम ज्ञेयं वंशगतं बुधैः।}}\\
\noindent{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{\relscale{1.4}वैण एव विधिस्तत्र स्वरग्रामसमाश्रयः॥}}
\end{sloppypar}
            \pend
            \pstart
\begin{sloppypar}\justifying\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}
\noindent{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{\relscale{1.4}३०.२}}\\
\noindent{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{\relscale{1.4}द्विकत्रिकचतुष्कास्तु ज्ञेया वंशगताः स्वराः।}}\\
\noindent{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{\relscale{1.4}कम्प्यमानार्थमुक्ताश्च व्यक्तमुक्तास्तथैव च॥}}
\end{sloppypar}
      \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
\begin{sloppypar}\justifying\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}
\noindent\hangindent=0.5cm Experts must recognize that the instruments made of bamboo belong to the class called Suṣira. The rules of functioning of this are based on the same units of Svaragrāma as those of string instruments.
\end{sloppypar}
            \pend
            \pstart
\begin{sloppypar}\justifying\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}
\noindent\hangindent=0.5cm The Svaras of the flute have two, three or four Śrutis. These (Svaras) become pronounced (either as the holes are) shaken, half released and fully released.
\end{sloppypar}
            \pend
            \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pages} 
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn’t an answer, but I’ve just realized `sanskrit` doesn’t declare the numerals, which can be done by adding `numbers/digits.native = ०१२३४५६७८९` in `\babelprovide` (in the optional argument). With it, `\localenumeral{digits}{5}` works (and `\localecounter`, too).